# Sweeping a B-rep body in 3D

Tags: algorithm, 3d, computational-geometry, cad

Is it possible to sweep a BREP body along a curve?
Are there any standard algorithms to do this?

What I am trying to achieve is I have a body moving in 3D space. I want to generate a body out of the space which the moving body occupies during its motion.The output body should occupy the exact same space which the moving body occupied during its motion.

I have a B-rep body and the transformations of the body at each frame.

For example I have a body(may be complex having holes) moving around an axis in a helical path. The output should be a body along the helical path. To check if I play the animation again the moving body should be exactly fit in the result body at every frame of the animation.

Comment: You may want to find BRep silhouette curves on the plane normal to helix and sweep them along the helix.